# Merge Sort implementation is giving runtime error?

Tags: c++, mergesort

I implemented mergesort for the following practice problem on code chef.
[Turbo Sort](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT). When I am running for some test cases I am getting correct answer but on submitting it throws Runtime SIGSEGV. Can anyone tell what could have gone wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *arr, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int L[1000000];
    int R[1000000];
    int res[1000000];

    int tempi = low;

    for(int  tempi = low; tempi <= high;tempi++)
    {
        if(tempi<mid+1)
        {
            L[tempi-low] = arr[tempi];
        }
        else
        {
            R[tempi-(mid+1)] = arr[tempi];
        }
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0,k = 0;

    while(i<mid+1-low && j<high-mid)
    {
        if(L[i]>R[j])
        {
            res[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            res[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }

        k++;
    }

    if(i == mid-low+1)
    {
        for(;j<high-mid;j++,k++)
        {
            res[k] = R[j];
        }
    }

    if(j == high-mid)
    {
        for(;i<mid+1-low;i++,k++)
        {
            res[k] = L[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i <high-low+1; i++)
    {
        arr[low+i] = res[i];
    }
}

void MergeSort(int* arr,int p,int r)
{
    if(r>p)
    {
        int q = (p+r)/2;
        MergeSort(arr,p,q);
        MergeSort(arr,q+1,r);
        merge(arr,p,q,r);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[1000000];
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    for(int i = 0; i< t; i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    MergeSort(a,0,t-1);

    for(int i = 0; i<t;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could it be that they are just testing it with more than million inputs??

Comment: If you go the link for the problem they mentioned bounds for size. It was 10^6. Which I m satisfying

Comment: Maybe they have smaller stack size than you have. ~12MB is a lot.

Comment: if stack was the issue all tests would fail I would think.  Either way worst following up on that.  Get rid of L and R arrays you don't really need them, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

"A SIGSEGV is an error(signal) caused by an invalid memory reference or a segmentation fault. You are probably trying to access an array element out of bounds or trying to use too much memory." Which means that at some point in your code you try to use a[i] where i<0 or i>1000000. Search for it, maybe with a debugger.